# How to show CircularProgressIndicator while build state is running in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a HomePage with DataTable with several hundred rows, which takes a while to load. The HomePageState reloads every time I sort the data table - while building, the whole page freezes for a second or two.

Is it possible to add a progress indicator, build the new state in the background and show it after the build is done?

In other words, I want this to happen when a user sorts the table:

1. CircularProgressIndicator shows up
2. The new state is shown after the new state is built

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping you are using `FutureBuilder` for getting data.

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchData(),
        builder: (_, dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            return Container(), // Your widgets code
            );
          }
        },
      )
```

inside else block get data like `dataSnapshot.data` -- Use this to render widgets.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I thought about FutureBuilder, but it didn't occur to me to use it this way - I've never used it before.